# When to remove TFS 2010 automatically created Workspaces

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration

Since almost one year we are running CI builds on our build machine. And the TFS creates a new workspace (ws) for each build, meanwhile we have many ws'.

So my questions (I didn't find a hint in the docs, though):

- Should we remove these "stale" ws' manually?
- Or is there any automatism in the TFS, so that it can handle or reuse these ws' somewhen? - Maybe configurable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These workspaces seem worthless, I wouldn't know how to make any use for them.

Using [TF-Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) (the "Workspace"-sidekick) & entering in the search criteria the name of the build-server it is possible to get a list of all those, now useless, workspaces.

We do this every one to two weeks, usually as part of the end-of-iteration cleanup.
I suspect that it shouldn't be hard to implement a console-app do this, I just haven't gotten round to investigate it. I could support in that, if you like.